# ng-if for comparing dynamic json values

Tags: html, angularjs

I am new to AngularJs
I have two JSON objects one is "products" and and another is "users"
I have two ng-repeat one is for product display and inside that to get user name of product i have another loop.
In the inner loop I need to check userId from product JSON and compare it with userId in User object and if matches display it in P tag.
My code is as follows:

```
<div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="(key,value) in products" style="padding-top: 1.4%; padding-bottom: 1.4%;" >
<img style="height:300px;width:350px" ng-src="{{products[key].image}}"></img>
<div ng-repeat="(userkey,value) in User">
<p ng-if="User[userkey].userId == products[key].user">{{{User[userkey].name}}</p> 
</div>
</div>
```

I have tried like this but it is displaying all users in p tag.
Can anyone please help with this

Comment: can you provide data's in `products` and `User` .

Comment: My sample data is like this : products data {'productId':'1','name':'abc','image':'temp.jpg','user':'user1','description':'This is my sample description for product'} user data {'userId':'user1','name':'test','address':'my address'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="product in products" style="padding-top: 1.4%; padding-bottom: 1.4%;" >
<img style="height:300px;width:350px" ng-src="{{product.image}}"></img>
<div ng-repeat="(oneUser in User">
<p ng-show="oneUser.userId == product.user">{{{oneUser.name}}</p> 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you print {{oneUser.userId}} and {{product.user}} and tell me what they show on the UI ?

Comment: If I use like that it is showing nothing.If I use like this User[userkey].userId and products[key].user It is showing exact user Ids. but I am not getting how to compare them in ng-if

Comment: Strange. Is your ng-repeat working ? Have you assigned $scope.products and $scope.users as arrays ?

Comment: Yse it is working perfectly and I am getting all user names in my UI.but I need only one user which matches product userId

Answer (score 1):

You could do that with filter:

```
 oneUser in User | filter: {userId:product.user}:true
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/3095/)

**EDIT**

The way you should do that is with filters, you could use ng-show/ng-hide but you are still rendering that item as a comment, while with filter it will not. So use this for large data.

Comment: Why it is not working for me if I use product.name.It is only working if use products[product].name.Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Maybe you are not repeating the same way the products...  in the fiddle you can see it is *ng-repeat="product in products"* ... while in your question you have it *(key,value) in products*

Comment: Yes I got it.I am using as "(key,value) inprodicts".Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me -

```
<div ng-repeat="p in products">
    <div ng-repeat="u in users">
        <p ng-show="u.userId == p.user">
            {{u.name}}
        </p> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/halirgb/Lvc0u55v/